# adb shell input text ignore characters

Tags: adb, shell, text-input

In android emulator adb shell I send the following command:

```
input text \!\$\#\?\%shelllllllooo
```

And result:

[image]

All same characters(exclude special like `!?#$`) been ignored.

Comment: Try wrapping what you want to send in quotation marks; i.e., `input text "\!\$\#\?\%shelllllllooo"`.  Also, keep in mind that `%s` will be treated like a space.